# Straight vs Straight + Highcard

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, poker-strategy

[image]

1s hand: J ♥️ 4♣️
2nd Hand: J♣️ K♣️

Table: 1♥️ K♦️ K♥️ Q♠️ 10♠️

Who wins this hand???

Comment: rough turnout, probably you thought you had it in the bag when you had trip kings

Answer (score 1):

Split:

For both of the players, best 5 cards is represented by the straight (AKQJT).